# Best response to shut down the fake Moon landing conspiracy

Tags: the-moon, moonlanding, theories

***This Question was closed for various reasons. For people looking for the answer to similar question, please see this [link](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/the-answer-to-the-question-about-moon-landing-hoax-theories). I believe this is a solid answer to my question.***

As the designated Space Cadet of my friends, I often have people come to me with questions regarding Outer Space. The most recent call came from a friend who was being aggressively told that the Moon landing was fake.

Now, we all know this is a conspiracy. In fact, conspiracy isn't actually the correct word per the definition. It's simply an incorrect claim. On top of this, we all have our return arguments to those who doubt the Moon landing. But I think anyone who has been in this argument has run into the typical conspiracy theorist issue:

**As soon as you prove one claim to be false, they hit you with another that you need to fight against.**

So, here is the question I ask all of us to think about:

**What is a *single* fact/argument that completely debunks the claim that the Moon landing was faked?**

(Emphasis on **single** fact/argument)

---

Disclaimer: I know that *technically* it isn't up to me to prove that the landing wasn't fake, but rather up to them to prove to me that it was fake. However, I still want to help people learn and be educated, so I would love some thoughtful answers to this question. Plus... I love a good argument (and I definitely love winning a good one too).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not even a little bit about Astronomy as defined in the help center. This is however somewhat on-topic in Space Exploration SE, and probably has answers there already. You can read about it in the meta site there: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=hoax

Comment: Also when talking about debunking conspiracy theories, you're up against things like the backfire effect, which is more a question about psychology.

Comment: More appropriate to [skeptics.se] I think.  But my experience is that people who deny e.g. the moon landings won't be convinced by anyone or anything.

Comment: Every now & again you will be involved in a argument/discussion/fight you will never will never win despite being correct. Some people aren't interested in facts &/or truth. They want to hold onto their ideas/opinions regardless of the consequences. Say what you know is correct & if the other person still holds incorrect ideas change the topic of discussion. Your sanity is worth more to you intact than the damage you might do trying to bash your head against a brick wall trying to convince someone else they are wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "when talking about debunking conspiracy theories, you're up against things like the backfire effect, which is more a question about psychology".  There isn't an astronomy answer here.

Comment: Darn, I thought this was a fun question that I couldn't find a solid answer to. Fair though, I agree with everyone. Plus, taking a look at the comment that @uhoh left, I found [this](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/the-answer-to-the-question-about-moon-landing-hoax-theories) right off the bat. Essentially gives a solid answer to this question. Soo good call everyone!

Comment: I think the real reason of the closure of your question is that this fake conspiracy theory about the fake Moon landing is so strongly disliked here, that it is disliked even if you are actually collecting arguments against it. Beside the skeptics SE, I suggest to try also the [site chats](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=astronomy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have no hearth to click "leave closed", but I don't want that this crap exist on the site, so I click "skip".